# R - change values in labelled column of dataframe without losing all labels in column

Tags: r, dataframe, label

I'm trying to learn how to work with the `sjlabelled` package in R, and labelled data more generally. I'm trying

Here's the output for what I tried for a very simple example:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(sjlabelled)
> 
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:3, 1:3),
+                  col2 = c(seq(11, 33, 11), 11, 12, 13))
> 
> df <- df %>%
+   set_labels(col1, labels = c("a" = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = 3)) %>%
+   set_labels(col2, labels = c("A" = 11, "B" = 12, "C" = 13, "D" = 22, "E" = 33))
> 
> df
  col1 col2
1    1   11
2    2   22
3    3   33
4    1   11
5    2   12
6    3   13
> 
> get_labels(df)
$col1
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$col2
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

> 
> df <- df %>%
+   mutate(col1 = ifelse(col1 > 1 & col2 < 33, 2, as_labelled(col1)))
> 
> df
  col1 col2
1    1   11
2    2   22
3    3   33
4    1   11
5    2   12
6    2   13
> 
> get_labels(df)
$col1
NULL

$col2
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

I have used `as_labelled` to preserve labels in other situations, such as when using `rbind` for data frames with labelled data, but it isn't working here.

Are either of the following possible using `sjlabelled` or a similar approach:

a) overwriting values with other values which had already been assigned a label so that labels are preserved and the overwritten value has its label overwritten with the corresponding label (e.g. any values that are overwritten as '2' in the example will now be labelled as "b")?

b) overwriting values with values which weren't in the column (e.g. NA) without losing the labels from the values which were already labelled (e.g. with the example, overwriting '1' and '2', with NA but keeping '3' labelled as "c")?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We could assign as

```
df$col1[with(df, col1 > 1 & col2 < 33)] <- 2
```

-checking

```
> get_labels(df)
$col1
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$col2
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

> df
  col1 col2
1    1   11
2    2   22
3    3   33
4    1   11
5    2   12
6    2   13
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. How do I check if the labels are still attached to the right values? Is there a way of printing the values and the labels together?

Comment: @DeeG by default, `get_labels` prints with `values= NULL`.  You can change that to `n` or `p` (prefix) i..e `get_labels(df, values = "n")` returns a named vector here